# Not correctly working static map server

Tags: skmaps, skobbler-maps

Since last week tiles server does not work correctly. Example:

```
http://tiles2-my_web_api_key.skobblermaps.com/TileService/static/2.0/00006110100/0/59.9959602355957,30.19530487060547,15/320x88.png@2x
```

Before this type of links works ok.

Web api key is correct.

Instead the image of map is loaded gray rectangle.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the tile server - our IT team is investigating

Comment: The problem has been solved - it will take some time until the CloudFront cache is updated